# Amazon EBS Type for MySQL Replication Server

Tags: mysql, replication, aws

I have the following topology

```
City 1                                                City 2
Master <----> Distribution Master (EC2 Instance) <---> Slave
```

- Master : Write heavy
- Distribution Master: Read only
- Slave: Read only

There won't be any application in front of Distribution Master.

Distribution Master is slave of Master and Master of SlaveServer
. Master and Slave are in different cities and the replication needs to be Asynchronous.

The EC2 instance just gets the data from Master and replicates to the Slave when a connection is established.

- Do you think I need SSD volumes for the Replication Master?
- Or will a cold HDD (sc1) will be enough?

With a cold storage solution I can get more space for a much lower price.

Comment: Hi Renko, welcome to the site. Unfortunately this question boils down to "what performance do you need?" and we really can't help with that. My advice is to profile and determine what your needs are, then use that to base your decision off it. If you're moving GBs of data or less, then you probably are fine with cold storage.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is off-topic, but before my thread get closed. Where can i make questions of this kind? I think Quora is too general purpose.

Comment: Yeah, in general it is too general purpose for this sort of thing. Honestly my experience in this case says you probably want ServerFault, because you're mostly asking about how to setup/configure a VM for best perf at lowest price, but they would probably scoff at that too. In your case the ideal thing to do is to gain a little more rep and join us in the chat rooms for this sort of question. Gain rep by asking great questions and providing great answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "distribution master" -- assuming it is running MySQL Server, not a specialized program specifically for directly replicating  binlogs -- cannot *"just get data from Master and replicate to the Slave when gets connection"* and relay the incoming events to downstream replicas.  It will also be keeping a copy of the entire data set and processing the replication events, keeping its local copy in sync before sending the events downstream.

It will, therefore, need to have as much I/O capacity as needed in order to keep up with the master.

The question of whether `sc1` Cold Storage (mechanical) HDD EBS volumes offer sufficient capacity in *both* write throughput and IOPS is not a question that can be answered in general.

**The answer depends entirely on your workload.**

There is nothing in `sc1` that is intrinsically incompatible with MySQL, but a 500 GiB `sc1` volume has a baseline throughput of only 6 MiB/s and a burst throughput of 40 MiB/s.  There is a reason it is marketed as "cold storage," and a reason it is inexpensive.

An `st1` Optimized Throughput (also mechanical) HDD volume has > 3x the performance for < 2x the price of `sc1` so is a somewhat safer bet.  I have recently begun testing `st1` volumes for binary log and relay log storage on some non-critical replicas -- with the datadir still on `gp2` SSD volumes -- and have not been seeing any replication lag nor taxing of these volumes according to the CloudWatch metrics nor significant iowait... but binary logs and relay logs are, of course, largely sequential write and read, which puts them within the design parameters of both `st1` and `sc1`.

The bottom line, though, is that your experience will be highly correlated to your workload.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html

---

Remember also that if you create a volume of any storage class from an EBS snapshot (such as when you are testing different storage classes -- a snapshot made from one type of volume can be used to create a volume of a different type) that you will see degraded performance until the volume is warmed up.

Assuming the volume is `/dev/xvdf`, this might look like `dd if=/dev/xvdf obs=1M | pv -pterab > /dev/null` ... followed by a few hours of waiting.  Don't try to optimize a warmup with `fio` or a large block sizes on smaller instances -- you'll DoS your own instance if you hit a stretch of already warmed-up blocks and the volume's read throughput spikes significantly above the available network bandwidth on the instance's Ethernet interface.  If this happens, the instance will fail its health checks.

Comment: sqlbolt Thank you very much for your answer. I'm newbie on DBA world, so my questions are very basic. There wont be any application in front of Replication master, so it works is get and send data to one or two slaves servers. All the work will made in Master (Write heavy) and Slave (Read only), the distribution master will be read only also.